# A trait with a Sized supertrait still has the error "std::marker::Sized is not satisfied"

Tags: rust, traits

I have the following code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait T: Sized {}

struct A;

impl T for A {}

fn main() {
    let h: HashMap<String, T>;
}
```

But the compiler complains:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:10:12
   |
10 |     let h: HashMap<String, T>;
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `T` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `T`
   = note: required by `std::collections::HashMap`

error[E0038]: the trait `T` cannot be made into an object
  --> src\main.rs:10:12
   |
10 |     let h: HashMap<String, T>;
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `T` cannot be made into an object
   |
   = note: the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized`
```

I don't understand the error messages, because I've marked my trait `T` as `Sized`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> because I've marked my trait `T` as `Sized`

No, you haven't. You've said that any type *that implements `T`* must be `Sized`. The *trait* itself is still unsized. You either need a trait object (e.g. `Box<T>`) or some kind of generic (which you cannot do in this context).

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, but I haven't found it yet. Let me know and I'll delete this and close as duplicate.

Comment: I couldn't find it either, so thank you!